# how to get the last auto generated alphanumeric id for mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having a table to store different types of products. I need to give an continuous alphanumeric id(like if item1 is book then id must be b0001, for item2 if it is pen id must be p0002 an so on). I am not able to achieve this functionality. Please someone help me.

Comment: ` I am not able to achieve this functionality` means you have tried something.  Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: functionality means for item1 prefix must have prefix 'b' then item2 must have prefix 'p'.

Comment: i was referring to the actual code you are creating. if `none` can you post example data or database structure to start with?

Comment: Do you need help for database design ? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use The MySQL [insert_id()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp) method, this return The last id generated in The last mysql insert.
Then you can increment this by one and use concatenation to add p at The begin of The string, after that you can put The string in The DB.

Answer (score 0):

First converting this column to binary and sorting the binary combined with tbl_column.

```
SELECT  
BIN(tbl_column) AS tbl_column
FROM table
ORDER BY  tbl_column DESC
```

Or We can use casting

```
SELECT  
CAST(tbl_column as SIGNED) AS tbl_column
FROM table
ORDER BY tbl_column DESC
```

For get the last auto generated id use `LIMIT 1`